# Как сделать печать в строчку

Tags: python

```
import time
def Animation (text):
    for x in list(text):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        print(x)

Animation('Тест')
```

Как сделать, чтобы печаталось в строчку, а не в столбик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте документацию про метод `print`. Например, [здесь](https://pythonz.net/references/named/print/). Он обладает несколькими необязательными аргументами. `sep` и `end`. Первый будет добавлять значение после каждого элемента, второй лишь раз в конце. По умолчанию `end` переводит каретку на новую строку. Измените это, например, на пробел и все элементы будут в одной строке.

```
text = 'Hello, World'
for t in text:
    print(t, end=' ')

# H e l l o ,   W o r l d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def Animation (text):
    s=''
    for x in list(text):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        s+=x
        print(s,end='\r')

Animation('Тест')
print('\n')
```